# Confusion Matrix in Keras+Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, keras, confusion-matrix

## Q1

I have trained a CNN model and saved that as `model.h5`. I am trying to detect 3 objects. Say, "cat", "dog" and "other". My test set has 300 images, 100 from each category. First 100 is "cat", 2nd 100 is "dog" and 3rd 100 is "other". I am using Keras class `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory`. Here is sample code:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='sparse',
        shuffle=False)
```

Now to use

`from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix`

`cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)`

I need `y_test` and `y_pred`. I can get `y_pred` using following code:

```
probabilities = model.predict_generator(test_generator)
y_pred = np.argmax(probabilities, axis=1)
print (y_pred)

[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2]
```

Which is basically predicting the objects as 0,1 and 2. Now I know that first 100 object (cat) is 0, 2nd 100 object (dog) is 1 and 3rd 100 object (other) is 2. Do I create a list manually using `numpy` where first 100 point is 0, 2nd 100 point is 1 and 3rd 100 point is 2 to get `y_test`? Is there any Keras class that can do it (create `y_test`)?

## Q2

How can I see the wrongly detected objects. If you look into `print(y_pred)`, 3rd point is 1, which is wrongly predicted. How can see that image without going into my "test_dir" folder manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using any augmentation and `shuffle=False`, you can simply get the images from the generator:

```
imgBatch = next(test_generator)
    #it may be interesting to create the generator again if 
    #you're not sure it has output exactly all images before
```

Plot each image in imgBatch using a plotting library, such as Pillow (PIL) or MatplotLib.

For plotting only the desired images, compare `y_test` with `y_pred`:

```
compare = y_test == y_pred

position = 0
while position < len(y_test):
    imgBatch = next(test_generator)
    batch = imgBatch.shape[0]

    for i in range(position,position+batch):
        if compare[i] == False:
            plot(imgBatch[i-position])

    position += batch
```

Comment: #Q2: I think that will plot every image in `test_generator`. I was wondering what could be the way to only plot the 'wrongly detected' images?

Comment: If the generator was a keras `Sequence`, you can take images by index, otherwise, you will have to get images until you reach the desired index.